# Can I share files in Chatter just to 1 single person?

Tags: chatter, chatter-file

i would like to ask if I post a files in a Chatter group all members in that group will be able to see the files. Is there anyway that I only want to share the file to a single member or chatter user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upload the file, click Sharing Settings and add the user you want using Share with People:

[image: Sharing Settings]